# distinct mongoose return undefined values javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm using mongoDB/mongoose and when i call distinct it returns undefined values, but in my database has values recorded.

I'm new in MVC, mongoDB, angular and I'm not know what I have to do.

Here is my controller

```
controller.listaClientes = function(req, res) {

  var filtro = {};

  Cliente.find(filtro)
    .distinct()
    .exec()
    .then(
      function(listagem) {
        res.json(listagem);
      },
      function(erro) {
        console.log(erro);
        res.status(500).json(erro);
      }
    );
};
```

and below are my module where a call the db requisition

```
$scope.clientes = [];
$scope.mensagem = {
  texto: ''
};

function buscaClientes() {

  Cliente.query(
    function(clientes) {
      $scope.clientes = clientes;
      $scope.mensagem = {};
      popularSelect(clientes);
    },
    function(erro) {
      console.log(erro);
      $scope.mensagem = {
        texto: 'Não foi possível obter a relação de clientes'
      };
    }
  );
}
buscaClientes();
```

Comment: Do you not need to specify what you want to run the distinct against inside the distinct? http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#distinct

Comment: yes, the field was 'regional', but this wasn't the problem. what happened it the property of $scope.clientes, which I've been called was absent so it was return to me undefined, but now works. Thanks for your help.